# in years that vs. in years when

Tags: grammar

The policy provides a “floor” that can protect you from market-related losses in years **that / when** the  indexes perform poorly.

THAT or WHEN? I say it's not a specific period of time. It's an essential clause -  a qualifying event. My team says otherwise.

Opinions?

Comment: I would go with "years in which."

Comment: I'd say "during years when," but this is for English SE.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much a language question, as a legal one. You need to understand the implications of using each word. To understand how each variation alters the legal meaning of the sentence. At that point you can choose which best aligns with your policy

Your question isn't 'which is grammatically correct' your question is about which one states your position. Decide your position and construct the language to suit that.

Comment: OK, fine it is a legal issue, but what does the difference mean?